# Google Maps API V3, XSD of Response XML

Tags: google-maps, xsd

I'm trying to parse Google-Maps XML response using JAXB. It'll be very nice to have XSD file provided by google. Anybody knows where to get it?

In case there is no existing xsd at all, anybody knows why google will not offer this schema officially? They themselves are probably also using this file in the meanwhile.

thanks,
user1146450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather my educated guess that there is no official XSD for what you're looking for; reason being the way the API documentation is written, specifically that it comes with a preferred processing model, which for XML responses is XPath based.

Google's XML is also not typical for a traditional Web Service described using a WSDL+XSD combination; it lacks XML namespaces, a violation of a WS-I Basic Profile rule R1014.

As to why, I think your question is poised to get rather personal views on the subject unless you're lucky to get an answer from an insider... At which point I shall delete my answer immeditely... Until then, this is my view on when the use of XSD might not be such a bright idea.

If there would be a world where only a pure XML processing stack would be available for development (e.g. XML, XSLT and the like, XML Appliances such as Datapower, Forum, Layer 7, etc.) then I would consider not providing an XML schema (XSD or other) almost a "crime".

If you throw in strong typed languages, such as Java and C#, then one loses a lot of the flexibility XML brings to the table. XSD was used as the main artifact to facilitate these "bindings" techniques; it both helped with the adoption of XML, and hindered what I call XML-based processing models, of which Google's XPath is one.

If the semantics are anchored with XPaths, then changes to an existing XML structure, as needed to accommodate new features, should not matter to an existing processor. But this is where JAXB and.NET bindings choke...

To alleviate some of this, people start using XSD features that for the average developer are too complex, or build XSDs that describe very abstract models. So now, one starts to have high burning rates trying to support all of this...

It might turn out that for simple structures, it might be cheaper from a support perspective to skip XSD all together; most of the people (anyway) want to see a sample XML to understand what the XSD is all about. If the spec owner decides to add new tags, anywhere s/he sees fit, no one can cry foul as an XPath-based extraction of data would always be impervious to such changes... Trying to do such a thing with XSD would either be impossible or very ugly...

And in Google’s case, if most of it is targeting the browser, why bother to answer “how do I validate XML using javascript?”... And no one wants server side applications crash royally every time one needs to add a new tag to the XML... For those thinking xsd wildcards are the answer, I argue it is not always possible (see UPA), or it affects XSD legibility, or that it actually brings the good XmlNode back into picture...

To sum it up, I am of opinion that XSD + (your language here) code bindings, in long run, caused more hassle, and employment ;) – than anything else!

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive analysis/answer, you are right, I will accept this answer if it'll not be answered "officially" in short time. I feel Google tried to write docs in easy way, but I don't know why, after several clicks I was always led to the EXIT... fortunately I've found some content I want to read by tenacious tries at last, I think imbecilic guys like me should not be hurt like this way -_-

Comment: @user1146450, just to make sure, I didn't mean to imply your approach of trying to use JAXB is wrong and for sure, even jokingly, I would never use the "imbecilic" epithet...

Comment: No I didn't mean that your answer made me feel stupid, but the docs of Google did. Maybe it's just too simple to believe that's all what the developers should know, so I tried to find XSD schema or something... anyway thank you again for the enlighten '_'

Answer (score 0):

I think that will help you. it shows how to use XPath to work with XML on Google Maps API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/index#ParsingXML

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -2):

(for example) 
You can receive an XML from a geocode query, then paste it to online XML to XSD creator. Finally, you need to edit the result to match different responses (I had to add target namespace and minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" to the  element to match multiple places).

You should get something like this (XSD for the above example)

```
 `https://pastebin.com/iV6w41ye`
```